# Building a Lightsaber with pretty much on electrical experience

Tags: batteries, amperage

I bought a third party toy fx style "lightsaber" recently. It only has the light effect which is brilliant. I wanted to add sound to it on a budget so I took the pcb out of an old style toy and wired it in. It works fine, however, the batteries become boiling to touch in under a minute. 
The saber, with just the light effect was powered by 3 AA batteries and the   board from the old toy was powered by 3 C cells. 
I've now got both the boards (with the wires that went to the bulb on the old board connected to the battery points on the new one) running off 6 AAAs wired from 2 caddies in serial.

So, questions are, why do the batteries feel like they are about to explode? and how do I make sure I'm not damaging the boards with under or over voltage? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 6 AAAs in series is over 9 volts. It sounds like each toy was originally powered by 4.5V. Additionally, C cells have WAY more capacity than AAAs. That alone could be the cause. Lots of issues here, and not enough information to know the answer for sure.

Comment: It sounds like you might be a young guy though. Don't give up, but take a step back and do some research and electronics tutorials on the web.

Comment: "_... with pretty much **on** electrical experience"?

Comment: They are getting hot due to being discharged in a way they aren't built for, the current draw they are being subjected to is causing them to heat up, I would use a larger battery, the ones used in high power laser pens do a good job, not sure of their name at the moment, will edit this with them later.

Comment: I'd post a picture if I could figure out how...? No, I'm not young! haha! I'm an artist, I've barely touched anything electrical since my school days. And clearly I rely too much on auto correct.

Comment: Ok, I've given up trying to run this as a single combined circuit. I'm gonna pick up a DPST switch and have them both powered independently. The only issue is space now. I can't fit all the AAs and Cs in the handle. Would running each of them on 3 lr50s work safety?

Answer (score 2):

First off, 3 AA batteries & 3 C batteries both (when wired in series) will produce ~4.5V (~3.6V if you use NiMH chemistries), but 6 AAA batteries (series wired) will produce ~9V (~7.2V NiMH). Using double the voltage ***will often cause serious damage*** to your device(s), and potentially to your person as well!

Please disconnect the 6 series-wired batteries before you have a fire start inside the toy.

Now, for why the batteries get soo hot; AA batteries are capable of producing much more current (I'll guess around 3x as much) than AAA batteries without heating up (due to lower internal resistance), and C batteries much more again than AAs (for the sake of argument, we'll assume 3x as much again here). Now, when you combine a device with C battery current demands in *parallel* with one which demands AA battery current, you could be demanding as much as 12x more current than those poor little AAA batteries were designed to efficiently put out! (and that's ignoring the excess current being forced through the circuitry by doubling the voltage)

Your "best bet" for running these 2 circuits would be to use the 3-series C batteries from the larger device, or mabe upgrade to a 3-series D battery pack if the C batteries don't last as long as you would like.

Comment: Thank you for a clear answer. C cells might just fit in the handle! I ran into an engineer today and asked for advice, he suggested replacing the batteries with a single Li-ion battery, such as one would find if mobile power banks. It'd have an output of around 4.5v? Would this be a possible solution?

Comment: The Li-ion is an option if it incorporates the safety circuitry (over and undervoltage and over current switches).  If you run a Li-Ion cell below the minimum voltage it goes bad and the little supervisor circuit prevents this when they are built in.

Comment: I've given up running them together and now have gone for 2 individual boards powered perfectly but operating from one switch. Unfortunately, one board uses a toggle, the other a momentary button. How do I replace a toggle with a momentary switch?!